# Minor mistake in calculation of extraterrestrial radiation (method 'asce')?

Tags: python, pvlib, solar

While looking at the code for the calculations of extraterrestrial radiation `get_extra_radiation()` and crosschecking it with literature, I noticed that for both methods 'asce' and 'spencer' the `solarposition._calculate_simple_day_angle(doy)` function is used. This function basically just calculates `(2. * np.pi / 365.) * (doy- 1)`, which is correct for method='spencer'.

But I think for method='asce' it should just be `(2. * np.pi * doy / 365.)` - without "- 1" - as described on page 9 in "*J. A. Duffie and W. A. Beckman,  "Solar Engineering of Thermal Processes, 3rd Edition" J. Wiley and Sons, New York (2006)*"

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where is this code coming from? Why should we know whether it's right or not?

Comment: I see from the tag that this is about `pvlib`. This posting would probably be better cast as a bug report to the `pvlib` support group.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question but a bug report, and SO is not the right venue for it.

Comment: The instructions here say to be nice to a new contributor...so I will.  :)

Comment: I was posting the question here, because on their website they list stackoverflow as one of the easiest ways to contribute. But I understand now, that this channel is reserved for more code related problems --> Question will be closed and a github issue will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happen to have this book in front of me, so I checked on page 9, and there is indeed a difference as noted w.r.t. the `pvlib-python` code.  One formula uses `n`, the other uses `n-1`.  This difference is probably not significant, but perhaps it should be fixed just so it is correct.  An issue on github would be the best way to raise this.